# Quadrature integration for complex function in R or Python

Tags: python, r, fft

Is there any function in R or Python based on quadrature to integrate the form of $$ \int ^{\inf}*{-\inf} e^{-it} f(t) dt $$ or $$ \int ^{\inf}*{-\inf} sin(t) f(t) dt$$ and $$ \int ^{\inf}_{-\inf} sin(t) f(t) dt$$ using quadrature?

Is there a function in either R or Python based on quadrature to integrate the form of [image] or

Comment: Can you please include code showing what you have tried and the results produced?

Comment: This integral is the complex number with real part $\int f(t) cos(t)$ and imaginary part $-\int f(t) sin(t)$. So you just have to calculate two integrals of a real-valued function. However the integrands are oscillatory and the integration can be unreliable.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Thanks for your reply. I was hopping to use quadrature formulas as it is fast and reliable. So i added the equivalent forms to my question to see if I can use quadrature.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you rewrite it as

F(w)= S exp<sup>-i w t</sup> f(t) dt, where `S` is integration sign, then this would be Fourier transform modulo some constants.

Then F(1) will produce value of the asked integral.

I would suggest with proper f(t) discretization use [FFTW library](https://pypi.org/project/pyFFTW/) or try NumPy FFT